# Writing tests with testing-library depends on implementation details of my UI library

Tags: testing, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer, angular-testing-library

I am using `@testing-library` to test my `React` project which uses `Material-UI` as it's main UI library. As `@testing-library` suggests, it's main philosophy is to test the application in the exact same way a user would use it. e.g click the button which says **Submit** or edit the input whose label is **Username**, etc... . And the testing-library gives me some helper methods like `getByText`, `getByLabel`, etc... .

My problem is that for some tests, forms' input tests for instance, I need to query an input's value or change it's current value. I need to `getByLabel` to query my label and go to parent component to query the input that is contained within. The library provides a `closest` DOM query helper, but is of no use in some situations, like the one I just described.

Writing my tests this way feels good, I mean writing tests as a user's point of view. But the problem is that I depend too much on implementation details of `Material-UI`. Maybe in next upgrade, the inputs and their corresponding label are not children of ancestor nodes, etc... .

Is there something I am doing wrong? Or is it the pitfall of the testing philosophy that `@testing-library` provides?

This is my packages stack:

```
{
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.7.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.34",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0-next.62"
}
```

Comment: You can use methods like `getByPlaceholderText` for instance to query an input field. I don't think we need to depend too much on the implementation details. You always have `getByTestId` method which can query by `data-testid`, yes it depends on the test id but not into implementation details.

Comment: Thanks @YugandharPathi . That's right, I can use `testId` as library suggests, But I love to stick to the lovely philosophy of testing things as user sees it